# Adding html with ng-repeat where the html also contains ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have code that binds html code to a div using a ng-repeat like so

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind-html="item.html">
```

In the html code passed in, I would like to add a table with an ng-repeat directive so that it can be populated with data when it is returned from a separate web service. My html in items.item looks like :

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat=\"person in people\">
    <td>{{person.id}}</td>
    <td>{{person.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{person.lastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Currently my output looks like

```
{{person.id}}   {{person.firstName}}    {{person.lastName}}
```

Any suggestions to get this to work?

Comment: It should work as you've written it. Are you sure you correctly bootstrapped your angular app?

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` doesn't compile the contents for you.

You can use this directive instead which is based on the source code for `ng-bind-html` but modified to also compile:

```
app.directive('compileHtml', ['$sce', '$parse', '$compile',
  function($sce, $parse, $compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function ngBindHtmlCompile(tElement, tAttrs) {
        var ngBindHtmlGetter = $parse(tAttrs.compileHtml);
        var ngBindHtmlWatch = $parse(tAttrs.compileHtml, function getStringValue(value) {
          return (value || '').toString();
        });
        $compile.$$addBindingClass(tElement);

        return function ngBindHtmlLink(scope, element, attr) {
          $compile.$$addBindingInfo(element, attr.compileHtml);

          scope.$watch(ngBindHtmlWatch, function ngBindHtmlWatchAction() {

            element.html($sce.trustAsHtml(ngBindHtmlGetter(scope)) || '');
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          });
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" compile-html="item.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile your html first using `$compile` service. You can look at the docs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile